# How do large dust storms impact the Martian poles?

Tags: mars

I was wondering why mars missions do not choose to land on the poles, as it should be safer weather-wise.

Comment: When you put a scientific machine on Mars, you put it there where it can do interesting science. Considerations of how comfy the machine feels up there are of second concern. Also you can design it to withstand certain stresses.

Comment: The question you asked in the title is different then the one in the body. I suggest you pick one of them and ask it. Both have some value. You might look in to improving it a bit by doing a bit more looking in to it, adding more text or something.

Comment: The poles are covered with ice, so you can't do geology there.